# Selecting second Dropdown Value Watir-Webdriver

Tags: ruby, watir

### Design:

First Dropdown:

```
<select id="MainContent_drpVehicleType" style="width:175px;" name="ctl00$MainContent$drpVehicleType">
<option value="">- SELECT -</option>
<option value="1" title="AUTO">AUTO</option>
<option value="2" title="HD">HD</option>
<option value="3" title="MARINE">MARINE</option>
</select>
```

Second Drop Down:

```
<select id="MainContent_drpMake" style="width:175px;" name="ctl00$MainContent$drpVehicleType">
<option value="1" title="ACURA">ACURA</option>
<option value="2" title="ALFA ROMEO">ALFA ROMEO</option>
<option value="74" title="ALLIS CHALMERS LIFT TRUCK">ALLIS CHALMERS LIFT TRUCK</option>
<option value="75" title="ALLIS CHALMERS TRACTOR">ALLIS CHALMERS TRACTOR</option>
<option value="4" title="AMERICAN MOTORS">AMERICAN MOTORS</option
</select>
```

### Code used for execution:

```
b.select_list(:id, "MainContent_drpVehicleType").select("AUTO")

b.select_list(:id, "MainContent_drpMake").select("ACURA")
```

and also tried

```
`b.select_list(:id, "MainContent_drpMake").wait_until_present.option(:text, 'ACURA')`
```

**What my Problem is able to select "AUTO" from first dropdown
and not able to select "ACURA"  from second dropdown

### Error While Executing:

```
C:/Ruby193/menu.rb:23:in `<main>': 
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.2/lib/watir-webdriver/el
ements/select.rb:218:in `no_value_found': "ACURA" not found in select list (Wati
r::Exception::NoValueFoundException)
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.2/lib/watir
-webdriver/elements/select.rb:152:in `rescue in select_by_string'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.2/lib/watir
-webdriver/elements/select.rb:149:in `select_by_string'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.2/lib/watir
-webdriver/elements/select.rb:131:in `select_by'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.2/lib/watir
-webdriver/elements/select.rb:64:in `select'
        from C:/Ruby193/menu.rb:23:in `<main>'**
```

Comment: Could you please state your prob in an easier way? what you wanted to ask here a bit clumsy,I think.

Comment: I just want to select "ACURA" value from Second dropdown .

Comment: is your second dropdown value depends on your first dropdown values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like your second dropdown is populated after the first dropdown value is selected. In that case, you need to wait for the second dropdown list to be populated (rather than for the second dropdown to appear).

You can wait for the specific option to appear and then set it by doing:

```
#The option element that you want:
option = b.select_list(:id, "MainContent_drpMake").option(:text => "ACURA")

#Wait for the option to appear
option.wait_until_present

#Set the option
option.select
```

Or if you want to do it on one line, you can use `when_present`:

```
b.select_list(:id, "MainContent_drpMake").option(:text => "ACURA").when_present.select
```

Comment: Humm, I also had the same doubt and asked him the same. but didn't get a response back from him.

Comment: @Justin Ko How to do that using `PageObject gem`?

Comment: @paul, you would need to define a method in your class. Depending on what exactly you want to achieve, you might override the default setter method for the select list.

Comment: I tried `@browser.select_list(user_drop_element).option(:text=>"Paul")` but its not working. And looks like its not `PageObject` way of doing it.